# Running jconsole on JRE

Tags: java

Is it possible to run the `jconsole` on `JRE`?
If not, is there any other way to see what is using the memory within the `JRE`?

I can see on the server stats itself that the JRE is using 70% of the server's memory,

I would like to see the detail of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JConsole is a tool which is used to monitor your java process which is executed in both remote and local environment. If you want to monitor your process connect to remote process by opening a port.

Comment: Will it run even though JDK isn't installed on the remote pc?

Comment: How difficult is the process to open this port? Would you be able to give me the steps to do this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html  http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/jconsole-jmx-remote-access-on-tomcat/

Answer (score -1):

The Java Server JRE as of release 8u45 ships with jconsole under /lib.

Comment: It won't be available in jre 8u45. Just now i verified.

Comment: What version did you download? Did you download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html)? Did you check under /lib like I said? 
I also checked before I replied...